# SwiftUI - Custom Identifier with Identifiable Protocol

Tags: struct, swiftui, protocols, identifiable

I'm wondering whether it's possible to override the standard identifier with a custom one.

I've a simple struct:

```
struct MyUserData: Identifiable {
    var userId: String
    var userFirstName: String
    var userLastName: String
}
```

However, the Identifiable protocol wont work without `var id: ObjectIdentifier` row inside the struct. At the same time, I don't want to use the "id" name. userId is also unique in my model (its a UUID). Is there a way to tell the identifiable protocol to accept "userId" instead of "id"?

Thanks!

Comment: Think the other way round: According to the [naming guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#naming) ***Omit needless words***, in your case `user`. Declare the three struct members `id`, `firstName` and `lastName` and you are done.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use any `Hashable` as an `id` property required by `Identifiable`:

```
extension MyUserData: Identifiable {
  var id: String { userId }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Unfortunately Identifiable requires a property called id. The easiest way to solve it is to use a computed property called id to your struct.

```
struct MyUserData: Identifiable {
    var userId: String
    var userFirstName: String
    var userLastName: String

    var id: String {
        userId
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need this one:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyUserData
{
    var userId: String
    var userFirstName: String
    var userLastName: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var arrayOfMyUserData: [MyUserData] = [MyUserData]()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List
        {
            
            ForEach(arrayOfMyUserData, id: \.userId)  { item in
                Text("FirstName: " + item.userFirstName) + Text("  LastName: " + item.userLastName)
            }
            
        }
        .onAppear() {
            
            arrayOfMyUserData = [MyUserData(userId: "userId1", userFirstName: "willy", userLastName: "will"),
                                 MyUserData(userId: "userId2", userFirstName: "bob", userLastName: "mccarthy"),
                                 MyUserData(userId: "userId3", userFirstName: "james", userLastName: "rodriguez")
            ]
            
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

Or you can use this:

```
struct MyUserData
{
    let userId: UUID = UUID()
    var userFirstName: String
    var userLastName: String
}
```